# passing array of data to php file from android does not enter in database

Tags: php, android, mysql, arraylist, foreach

I want to pass array of `String` **(itemname)** to a php file **(PlaceOrder.php)** using name value pair.
When I click on **PlaceOrder** `button` it passes **null** value in database. Is there any problem in **Android code or Php code**?
My Android code is following

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/demo/PlaceOrder.php");
              Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
              List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            for (int i=0;i<1;i++)
            {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ItemName[]", String.valueOf

(resultArrItemname[i])));

            }
            Log.e("log_tag", "Name value pair success ");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.e("log_tag", "response sucess ");
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
             showDialog("Order Placed Successfully");

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

and my PHP code is follwing

```
<?php

        $itemname[]=$_REQUEST['ItemName[]'];   

        mysql_connect("localhost","root","aaaaaa") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("demo") or die(mysql_error());          

        foreach($itemname as $key)
        {
            $sql=mysql_query("Insert into tblorder(itemname) values('$key')");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
        $output[]=$row;
             print(json_encode($output));
        }
         mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Try to generalize your question inspite of using name of files that you have

Comment: Try this and see if it helps at all:  "$itemname[]=$_POST['ItemName'];"

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
$itemname[]=$_REQUEST['ItemName[]'];
```

to

```
$itemname[]=$_REQUEST['ItemName'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$itemname[]=$_REQUEST['ItemName[]'];`

to

```
$itemname=$_REQUEST['ItemName'];
```

Remove `[]` from both side

Use query like below :

```
$sql=mysql_query("Insert into tblorder(itemname) values('".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."')");
```

mysql_* functions are deprecated, use mysqli_* and PDO

Change :

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
$output[]=$row;
```

To :

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $output[]=$row;
}
```

Declare `$output = array();` just above the foreach loop

i guess you need to `print(json_encode($output));` after foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

$itemname[]=$_REQUEST['ItemName[]'];

It is not better way to use..
Try POST or PUT or other input types...
Request may be harmful in future development...

Try ---- $itemname[]=$_POST['ItemName'];